# On two-colorings of the plane

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

Suppose that we have colored any point in the plane with two colors and let $n\geq 3$ be given. I want to show that there are $n$  points such that together with their centroid all have the same color.

Comment: You are in fact going to have $n$ monochromatic points in arithmetic progression for any $n$ (van der Waerden's theorem). If $n$ is odd that gives the result. If you want the result for $m$, and $m$ is even, take $2m+1$ points in arithmetic progression, and pick a suitable subset of $m$, so the centroid is still one of the original $2m+1$ points.

Comment: And more generally there is Gallai's theorem: for any finite coloring $\mathbb R^d=C_1\cup\dots\cup C_k$ there is some color $i$ such that $C_i$ contains, for each finite set $S\subset\mathbb R^d$, a homothetic (similar without rotating) copy of $S$. For your question, $d=k=2$, and you can let $S$ consist of $n-1$ equally spaced points on a circle and the center of the circle. (The Hungarian name Gallai is pronounced as three syllables with the accent on the first syllable.)